# How to apologise in French

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, culture

I was wondering, if one was to hurt somebody accidentally what would be an appropriate way of apologising?

For example if a child were to hit an elder while on their bicycle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> - Pardon !
> - Excusez-moi !
> - Désolé ! (Québec)

Sont les réponses 'réflexes' possibles.

Excuses plus formelles :

> - Je vous demande pardon.
> - Je suis désolé, est-ce que je peux vous aider.

Très soutenu :

> - Je vous prie de bien vouloir m'excuser.
> - Je vous prie de pardonner mon geste, mon erreur, ...

---

*Ajout pour répondre aux commentaires sur la formulation*  Je m'excuse *de la réponse de* Papa Poule.

Le petit Robert est très clair :

> *Je m'excuse* s'emploie incorrectement pour *excusez-moi*.

La formule acceptée pour *je m'excuse* ne correspond pas à la situation de la question : il ne s'agit pas d'un mouvement de regret suite à une maladresse où *je* s'exprime dans l'instant et s'adresse à l'offensé.
mais où le *je* qui s'excuse motive son remord, le met en situation et ne s'adresse pas obligatoirement à la personne offensée.

Il est préférable de ne pas utiliser *je m'excuse* en réponse immédiate à une action regrettable, sinon on risque de passer pour un mufle ou d'avoir des réactions de colère justifiée.

Comment: Je vous remercie.

Comment: Although it’s ambiguous in the first person [*Qui s'excuse s'accuse*] and certainly wouldn’t be appropriate, correct, or acceptable in your particular example, the reflexive verb “(s)’*excuser*,” in addition to meaning “to present one’s excuses” also means “to express one’s regrets” for something, and I’ve heard many feeble (non) apologies, especially from politicians, begin with “**Je m’excuse**.”

Comment: *Je m'excuse* est employé, souvent par les enfants, mais c'est un non sens : on ne peux *s'excuser soi-même* car quand on *excuse quelqu'un*, on le décharge d'une faute, ou on justifie l'erreur commise par quelqu'un en lui trouvant des circonstances atténuantes. *Excusez-moi* : ordonner à quelqu'un de pardonner ses propres fautes n'est pas poli, mais d'un usage courant dans la réaction immédiate et sera plus facilement accepté. Pour présenter ses excuses réfléchies, il faut inviter l'offensé à pardonner : "Je vous prie de bien vouloir m'excuser pour ... "

Comment: J'ai entendu beaucoup « je m'excuse » chez les adultes. C'est impoli ?

Comment: I don’t find it automatically impolite, but it is ambiguous & it does invite confrontation if the aggrieved party chooses to reject it as an adequate apology as follows: «Tu t’excuse peut-être, mais moi, je ne te pardonne pas»  

I find it similar to the (over)use in English of “I’m sorry” all alone to express regret in order to try to elicit forgiveness without accepting responsibility by adding “I was wrong, please forgive me.”  

While “I’m sorry” isn’t automatically impolite, it can be met with «“Sorry” don’t cut it, Mister» if the aggrieved party chooses to pursue the matter.@hunter

Comment: @cl-r Peut-être que vous avez raison, mais http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/je_m%E2%80%99excuse dit que ***je m’excuse*** est synonyme de ***je vous présente mes excuses.***

Comment: @cl-r: `s'excuser` est la forme pronominal de `excuser`. Le sens est bien synonyme de `présenter des excuses` (Ça reste ambiguë de par la confusion avec la forme transitive, comme souligné par @PapaPoule)

Comment: @PapaPoule J'ai ajouté une rubrique sur ma réponse.

Comment: @njzk2 J'espère que mon ajout lèvera l’ambiguïté que vous relevez.

Comment: L'usage voudrait que l'on explicite le vote négatif, ne serait-ce que pour l’amélioration de la réponse.

Answer (score 3):

To add a bit from Québec, we often shorten *Exusez-moi* to a shorter form

> 'Scusez!

or

> 'Scuses-moi

Please note that this is really informal, but probably what you would use if you bump into someone in the street!

Answer (score 3):

*Veuillez m'excuser !* is still imperative, but is perhaps slightly more polite/old-fashioned/deferential than *Excusez-moi !* because the latter doesn't even consider whether the other person will **want** to excuse us, and the former admits that they might not want to.