# "I apologize for the inconvenience", "Je m'excuse pour l'inconvenient" et "Je tiens à m'excuser pour la gêne occasionnée"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, correspondance, email

Dans quel contexte

> "I apologize for the inconvenience"

peut-être rendue par

> "Je m'excuse pour l'inconvenient"

et dans quel contexte par

> "Je tiens à m'excuser pour la gêne occasionnée"

?

J'ai mal saisi la note d'un étudiant. Il m'envoyé un e-mail pour signaler ma faute. Puis-je lui répondre en écrivant

> "Votre note a été rectifiée. Je m'excuse de l'inconvenient."

ou bien

> "Votre note a été rectifiée. Je tiens à m'excuser de la gêne occasionnée."

?

Comment: Faites-gaffe en osant croire que "je m'excuse" (et peut-être même "je tiens à m'excuser") peut servir pour demander pardon!  J'osais le croire et le proposer en répondant à [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12553) il y a 5 ans mais [ma réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/12556/6011), avec ses 2 votes positifs, était "deleted and converted to [a comment](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12553/how-to-apologise-in-french/12554#comment23012_12554)."

Comment: Voir aussi: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2812/je-mexcuse-ou-excusez-moi-ou-je-vous-pr%c3%a9sente-mes-excuses

Comment: @PapaPoule … il m’est arrivé d’en subir aussi les rigueurs, surtout dans ces temps de la préhistoire du Web, et depuis  : https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/759/une-autre-d%c3%a9mission.

Comment: @cl-rSOrendezconfianceenFL ... way back before we needed to be told to "be nice" to each other, or at least to "New Users" ...

Comment: @PapaPoule Je ne comprends pas. Donner des raisons pour se justifier, demander pardon pour quelque chose : Je m'excuse de mon retard. (https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/s_excuser/32051)

Comment: @PapaPoule https://www.deepl.com/en/translator#en/fr/I%20apologized%20for%20my%20mistake.

Comment: @Dimitris Regarde le lien que j'ai fourni. Une opinion répandue est que *je m'excuse* peut sous-entendre *je ne vous demande pas de m'excuser, je le fais moi-même*. Une justification étant par exemple qu'en anglais, on ne dit pas: *I excuse myself* ou *I forgive myself* mais bien *excuse me*, *forgive me*. C'est pourquoi on recommande souvent de l'éviter en dehors de contextes informels.

Comment: You are preaching to the choir, Dimitris, because in 2014 I didn't (& still don't) understand either! Since my skill at conveying sarcasm in French obviously needs improving (as do my basic French skills), I'll give it another shot in English [with hopefully clarifying embellishments]: "Take heed when daring to believe [on this forum] that *je m'excuse* can be used to *demander pardon*, [because when] I dared [not only] to believe it but to [actually] propose it in [one of my first FSE answers] over 5 years ago, my answer was [met with opposition & summarily and inexplicably] deleted."

Comment: @PapaPoule Now I got it! Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @jlliagre Donc I apologize does not have an alternative in France ?

Comment: There are hopefully many ways to apologize in French. Do you get my point about the potential issue with: "I excuse myself" or "I forgive myself"?

Comment: We can put in parallel: *pardonnez-moi* and *excusez-moi*. We never say *je me pardonne* but *je m'excuse* is common. Some purists consider the latter to be potentially rude so it is better to avoid it. In any case, it is always better to say *je m'excuse* than not to apologize at all ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Yes I got it. Thanks. Actually it was the FLE prof (no native speaker) that she told me that I cannot use inconvénient for conveying inconvenience in "I apologize for the inconvenience" and suggest me that I use rather  "Je m'excuse pour la gêne occasionnée". She wasn't familiar with this particular potential issue.

Comment: A famous Fernand Raynaud's quote is *Je m'excuse de vous demander pardon* :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Même si les significations de "**gêne**" et "**inconvénient**" sont proches, le mot "**inconvénient**" est généralement utilisé pour exprimer un jugement de valeur ou une préférence concernant les caractéristiques d'une situation ou d'un objet :

> Parmi les inconvénients de la vie parisienne, on peut citer la pollution, les embouteillages et les gens grincheux.

Dans cet exemple, on comprend que vivre à Paris peut présenter certains désavantages par rapport à la vie en province.

En l'occurrence, les mots "**gêne**", ou encore "**désagrément**", ou même "**dérangement**" semblent donc plus appropriés.

> Je tiens à m'excuser pour la gêne occasionnée.
>
> Je tiens à m'excuser pour le désagrément causé.

---

Even if the meaning of "**gêne**" and "**inconvénient**" are close, the word "**inconvénient**" is mostly used to express a value judgement or a preference about the caracteristics of a situation or an object:

> Among the drawbacks of parisian life are pollution, traffic jams and grumpy people.

Here we understand that life in Paris may have some disadvantages compared to life in a smaller city.

In this case, the words "**gêne**", or "**désagrément**", or even "**dérangement**" therefore seem more appropriate.

> I want to apologize for the inconvenience.